# How to Call existed Activity from Service【not Create new Activity, Use the already exist activity in memory】

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I know how to call an new activity from service as follows:

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

In my case, I want Service call an existed Activity, not NEW an activity.

My application is in a chat Module, I need to continue to chat with someone, when received

and Message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the gui from a service the article [How to Update the UI in an Android Activity Using Data from a Background Service](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/)
may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Manifest file Launch mode of singleTask, this will make sure it is the only activity in the task

[Refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)